# Why does removeChild need a parent node?

Tags: javascript, dom, removechild

After answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416664/iframe-javascript-remove-div-child-elements) I am left wondering why [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild) needs a parent element. After all, we could simply do

```
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
```

As the parent node should be always directly available to the Javascript/DOM engine, it is not strictly necessary to supply the parent node of the node that is to be removed.

Of course I understand the principle that `removeChild` is a method of a DOM node, but why doesn't something like `document.removeNode` exist (that merely accepts an arbitrary node as parameter)?

**EDIT:** To be more clear, the question is: why does the JS engine need the parent node at all, if it already has the (unique) node that's to be removed?

Comment: The DOM is an object-oriented concept. That means it would make more sense if `Node.prototype.remove` would exist to remove the node itself than if `Document.prototype.removeNode` would exist to remove a node from the document. Because the latter would simply be implemented by calling `removeChild` on the node’s parent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it keeps the design simple. A node *may* exist in isolation but the more interesting case is the DOM tree. With `removeChild`, the node to be removed must be a child of the node on which the method was called.

Getting a list of all children and doing a manual comparison against each is not that expensive an operation. However, searching all descendants for a node that is to be removed is indeed expensive.

**Edit**: In response to your update, a browser is simply implementing the [DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#i-Document), which defines a [`removeChild`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1734834066) method on `Node`. The spec, *in my opinion*, has to be unambiguous and free of assumptions. It is similar to [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) from that perspective. The DOM Core spec models a tree using building blocks such as Node, Element, etc. Adding a lone method such as `removeNode` somewhere in these building blocks means the method has implicit knowledge about its environment - that it `may` be a child of some node, and it should be removed from there if it is.

The task of w3 is to make a very robust API which makes most things possible. They shouldn't worry about syntactic sugar as that can always be written around the native APIs if they are well written.

Comment: Just one more side note: Diego Perini [said](http://twitter.com/diegoperini/status/20580063920) that IE and Opera actually support a [`removeNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536708%28VS.85%29.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion might be because you might think removing an element means something like killing or destroying it.

[image]

But in fact, the concept of [removal](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-node-remove) basically means breaking the relationship between a child and its parent. It's just a detachment.

[image]

Therefore, removing a element which has no parent node makes no sense. And it's reasonable that, if you want to break that connection between a parent and a child, you need a reference to both.

That said, it's true that sometimes you just want to remove a child from its parent, without caring about that parent at all. That's why DOM Level 4 introduces the [`ChildNode`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#interface-childnode) interface, which provides the [`remove`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-childnode-remove) method.

That interface is implemented by [`DocumentType`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#documenttype), [`Element`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#element) and [`CharacterData`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#characterdata), so you can use it on [doctypes](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-doctype), [elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-element) and [`Text`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#text), [`Comment`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#comment), and [`ProcessingInstruction`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#processinginstruction) [nodes](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-node).

Assuming `node` is one of these, you can use

```js
node.remove();
```

In case it already has no parent node, nothing happens.