# DOM manipulation - Why removeChild() method instead of remove()?

Tags: javascript, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does removeChild need a parent node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422370/why-does-removechild-need-a-parent-node)

Cross-browsers way to remove a node element is to use `removeChild()` method. 
However, this way expects us to precise the node's parent as follows:

```
myNodeToRemove.parentNode.removeChild(myNodeToRemove);
```

Why didn't browsers implement the remove method with a more object-oriented way like this:

```
myNodeToRemove.remove();
```

With `remove()` method starting as follows:

```
function remove(){
  var parentNode = this.parentNode;
  ....
}
```

Indeed, using this way, no need to manually get the node's parent.

Comment: Probably to replicate that of `appendChild()`, `replaceChild()` and `insertBefore()`. Who knows, though? It's what the nice guys at W3 decided.

Comment: Maybe... I find that very weird.

Comment: I guess its the parent's responsibility to decide if its child has become useless enough to end the suffering.. its all about ethics. On a less serious note look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3422497/149636

Comment: @dystroy I already read this post, but it doesn't really answer the same question.

Comment: I've read again the question, it's exactly the same.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the earlier question, *and* "not constructive" (see the FAQ, this requires opinion and speculation).

Answer (score 1):

For the question:

Why didn't browsers implement the remove method with a more object-oriented way like this

```
myNodeToRemove.remove();
```

...you need to study Javascript history, how the language was born, how APIs were born and so on. Then you understand how we ended up with the clusterfuck called modern web. The history is hilarious.

Good place to start is to watch Crockford on Javascript videos

http://javascript.crockford.com/#video

Also regarding function naming and object-oriented practices this is a good video:

http://vimeo.com/43380467

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason to use the combination of parentNode and removeChild ensures that we are referencing the removeChild method on the actual parent of the container that we wish to remove.

Comment: This would be the same guarantee using my custom remove() suggested method.